# Remove decimal places in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal

I have the following code in my model:

```
def calculate_10_key(self):
    if self.dimensional:

        if self.height == 1.25:
            height_display = 54
        else:
            height_display = self.height

        self.ten_key_shortcut = "%s0%s0%s" % (height_display, self.width, self.length)
```

The challenge I am having is my self.height, self.width, and self.length are all decimal fields to the 4th decimal place (which I need them to be for other calculations) but in this instance I need them to be a whole number (no rounding is necessary just the number to the left of the decimal). I know how to do this in a template with filter but am not sure how to do in this model code?

I appreciate the feedback and expertise.

Comment: Can you use regular string formatting?  `'%0d' % 1.25` results in the string `'1'`.

Comment: string formatting worked great! thanks